# Akka Streams: Copy element to another stream via alsoTo

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I want to use [`alsoTo`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/alsoTo.html) to copy the elements from one `Source` to another, but it does not work as I'm expecting. An example of code which creates an Akka `Source` from a Java `InputStream` and does some transformation and uses `alsoTo` to create a copy of `s1`:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.IOResult
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source, StreamConverters}

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("AkkaStreams_alsoTo")
    implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    val byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("a,b,c\nd,e,f\ng,h,j".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    try {
      val s1: Source[List[List[String]], Future[IOResult]] = StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => byteStream)
        .map { bs =>
          val rows = bs.utf8String.split("\n").toList
          val valuesPerRow = rows.map(row => row.split(",").toList)
          valuesPerRow
        }
      // A copy of s1?
      val s2: Source[List[List[String]], Future[IOResult]] = s1.alsoTo(Sink.collection)
      println("s1.runForeach: ")
      Await.result(s1.runForeach(println), 20.seconds)

      println("s2.runForeach: ")
      Await.result(s2.runForeach(println), 20.seconds)

      println("Done")
      system.terminate()
    }
    finally {
      byteStream.close()
    }
  }
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
s1.runForeach: 
List(List(a, b, c), List(d, e, f), List(g, h, j))
s2.runForeach: 
Done
```

As you can see, `s2.runForeach` doesn't print any elements. What is the reason of such behavior--is it because of a side effect when it reads the Java `InputStream`?

I'm using Akka Streams v2.6.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use `alsoTo` to copy the elements from one `Source` to another, but it does not work as I'm expecting.

`alsoTo` doesn't copy elements from a `Source` to another `Source`; it effectively copies the elements from a `Source`/`Flow` and sends them to another `Sink` (the argument to the `alsoTo` method). Therefore your expectation is incorrect.

> As you can see, `s2.runForeach` doesn't print any elements. What is the reason of such behavior--is it because of a side effect when it reads the Java `InputStream`?

Because `byteStream` is a `val`, both `s1.runForeach(println)` and `s2.runForeach(println)` "share" this instance even though they are *two distinct* Akka Stream blueprints. Therefore, when `s1.runForeach(println)` is called, `byteStream` is consumed, and when `s2.runForeach(println)` is executed afterward, there is nothing left in the `InputStream` for `s2.runForeach(println)` to print.

Change `byteStream` to a `def`, and the following is printed:

```
s1.runForeach: 
List(List(a, b, c), List(d, e, f), List(g, h, j))
s2.runForeach: 
List(List(a, b, c), List(d, e, f), List(g, h, j))
Done
```

That explains why `s2.runForeach(println)` doesn't print anything in this particular case, but it doesn't really show `alsoTo` in action. Your setup is flawed because `s2.runForeach(println)` just prints the elements from the `Source` and ignores the materialized value of `alsoTo(Sink.collection)`.

One easy way to see the behavior of `alsoTo` is the following:

```
val byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("a,b,c\nd,e,f\ng,h,j".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

val s1: Source[List[List[String]], Future[IOResult]] =
  StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => byteStream)
    .map { bs =>
      val rows = bs.utf8String.split("\n").toList
      val valuesPerRow = rows.map(row => row.split(",").toList)
      valuesPerRow
    }

val stream = s1.alsoTo(Sink.foreach(println)).runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
                                          // ^ same thing as .runForeach(println)
Await.ready(stream, 5.seconds)
println("Done")
system.terminate()
```

Running the above prints the following:

```
List(List(a, b, c), List(d, e, f), List(g, h, j))
List(List(a, b, c), List(d, e, f), List(g, h, j))
Done
```

The elements in the *one* `Source` are sent to *both* `Sink`s.

If you want to use `Sink.collection`...

```
val (result1, result2) =
  s1.alsoToMat(Sink.collection)(Keep.right).toMat(Sink.collection)(Keep.both).run()
 // ^ note the use of alsoToMat in order to retain the materialized value

val res1 = Await.result(result1, 5.seconds)
val res2 = Await.result(result2, 5.seconds)
println(s"res1: $res1")
println(s"res2: $res2")
println("Done")
system.terminate()
```

...which prints...

```
res1: List(List(List(a, b, c), List(d, e, f), List(g, h, j)))
res2: List(List(List(a, b, c), List(d, e, f), List(g, h, j)))
Done
```

Again, the elements in one `Source` are sent to two `Sink`s.